# Spring url not resolving correctly first time jsp page is loaded, works correctly after first hit

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Source code:

```
<c:url var="images" value="/images/" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="${images}myImage.png">
```

In firebug, first hit (the sessionid changes each time)

```
 <link href="/images/;jsessionid=05083AEAAE29DE81A5CB390407041282myImage.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
```

Second hit (without clearing cache, if I clear cache it goes back to above)

```
<link href="/images/myImage.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
```

So obviously the first time I hit website it looks bad as no resources are being loaded correctly.

Help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jessionid` part is the client session ID, and the first time you hit the page you're likely getting a cookie, so that on the next time you hit the page it doesn't need to be pushed into the URLs.  Looking at the JSTL def'n for `c:url`, you should be giving it the whole URL, not a partial path, so this would be the correct approach:

```
<c:url var="images" value="/images/myImage.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="${images}">
```

See also [A JSTL primer, Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/#N10533).